# Compare 2 array's elements against each other and return count JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays that I need to compare against each other and return the count of the same.

Example: compare array1 [abcd] against array2 [adce]. Return would be 2,1 as both a and c are in same position and d is in the wrong position.

```
function () {
    var index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (array1[index] == array2[index]) {
            count++
        } 
    }
    return count
}
```

I'm getting a return of 1. I think that's because they equal in length that is why I'm getting a 1. So I'm thinking that I now need to put another `for` loop and have that loop go through the elements individually, but not sure how to do this. I could be completely wrong in what I have put above, if so, could someone explain the process to me please.

Comment: Logic behind `2,1`...??

Comment: @Prasath K  2 in the array and in the right place, 1 in wrong place but still in the array

Comment: Still we coudn't get what you need .. What's your expected result..??

Comment: @Prasath K  I need to find the absolute matches.. for example: [abcd] compared to  [adce] this would mean that a and c were the only 2 that had the same postion in each array, so result would be 2....

Comment: do you mean, `char` match of string elements in array or just element match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `1` as output because `length` is not defined in your code

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['a','d','c','e'];

var length = Math.min(array1.length,array2.length);
var countMatched = 0,countNotMatched = 0;

for(var index=0;index<length;index++)
{
  if(array1[index] == array2[index])
    countMatched++;
  else if(array2.indexOf(array1[index]) >= 0)
    countNotMatched++;
}
alert(countMatched );
alert(countNotMatched);
```

Demo Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tCKE7/2/

Comment: I put in what you said but I get 4. Is this because the input is abcd and not 'a','b','c','d', so would I need to split them for it to work?

Comment: What's your input ...?? A string or an array ...??

Comment: input is abcd but is changed to index form 0,1,2,3 with another function, sorry I should have been clear on this, didn't know if it would make a difference and out, actually i am confused... how do i tell if it is an array or string

Comment: if you give the array as i specified , you will get the count of matched elements

Comment: yes thank you , i forgot to bring my other function in... So what would be the process to go about finding and returning the values that didn't match positions in the array's but was in the array's. I would like to do myself thank you, but not sure where to start.

Comment: Oh ok ... You need to find the element's position or number of elements that doesn't match but it is in array ...??

Comment: 'the number of elements that don't match but are in the array, but looks like this has been answered below. I will look at it and work out how he got to the solution. thank you for all your help.

Comment: @52876 Just do a refresh and check out my answer , link

Answer (score 1):

There is a JS library [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) which provides a number of useful method for processing JavaScript arrays. You can use its difference method:

```
_.difference(['a','b','c','d'], ['a','d','c','e']) // returns ["b"]
```

Comment: `_.difference(['a','b','c','d'], ['a','d','c','e']).length` would be what OP wants. anyways, `lodash` seems to be faster than `underscore` atleast as per the benchmarks given by lodash creator.

Comment: I'm using underscore together with backbone

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret correctly, you want to find a count of elements that are at the same, exact position and a count of elements that are present in both arrays but not at the same position.

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var array2 = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'e'];
var largerArray = (array1.length > array2.length)? array1 : array2;
var shorterArray = (largerArray == array1)? array2 : array1;
var count = {
             exactPosition: 0, //elements at the exact position 
             wrongPosition: 0 /*elements present in both arrays but at the wrong position*/
            };
//loop the larger array
for(var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i ++) {
    if(array1[i] == array2[i]) {
        count.exactPosition ++;
    }
    //find elements at the wrong position in `largerArray`
    else if(largerArray.indexOf(shorterArray[i]) != -1) {
        count.wrongPosition ++;
    }
}

alert(count.exactPosition);
alert(count.wrongPosition);
```

This isn't a rock-solid approach and would not work for duplicates.

[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crAAJ/)

Comment: Thank you for this, I missed this all together so don't think I was disregarding it.