# How to compare 2 arrays and get count of each matching item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Say an AJAX call returns 2 arrays on success. The arrays returned are different everytime, but there could be some elements in common. For example,

```
array1 = [a, b, c, d]
array2 = [a, b, b, b, a, c, b, c, c]
```

Now I want to get the number of times each element of array 1 appeared in array 2, in this case, the results would be:

```
a: 2
b: 4
c: 3
d: 0
```

I have the following code that compares the two arrays, but I can't figure out how to keep a counter, do I have to construct a new 2d array for each element of array1? In which case, how do I construct the array without knowing the elements inside of it first?

```
success: function (array1, array2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array2[j] == array1[i]) {
        console.log("found match: " + array2[j]);
        // counting 
        // count should go up by 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare 2 array's elements against each other and return count JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783824/compare-2-arrays-elements-against-each-other-and-return-count-javascript)

Comment: There is a javascript library that does all this kind of stuff for you at http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c'];

var result = {}

array1.forEach(function(item) {
    result[item] = 0
})

array2.forEach(function(item) {
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        result[item]++
    }
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you just need to loop through `array1` to get the unique values, then you can use `filter()` to find how many of them exist in the second array. Try this:

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c'];

var result = {};
array1.forEach(function(item) {
  result[item] = array2.filter(t => t == item).length;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows in O(n);

```js
var arr1   = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    arr2   = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "c"],
    result = arr2.reduce((h,p) => (h.hasOwnProperty(p) && h[p]++, h) ,arr1.reduce((m,k) => (m[k] = 0,m),{}));
console.log(result);
```